# mdbreact default styling not loading in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, styling, mdbreact

I created a new react app, then I created a registration form component using mdbreact and everything was loading well. All of a sudden, the default styling associated with mdbreact suddenly stopped loading.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { MDBContainer, MDBRow, MDBCol, MDBBtn, MDBCard, MDBCardBody, MDBInput  } from 'mdbreact';

class Registration extends Component {
 
  render() { 
    return (          
        <MDBContainer>
        <MDBRow className="d-flex justify-content-center">
          <MDBCol md="6">
            <form>
              <p className="h5 text-center mb-4">Sign up</p>
              <div className="grey-text">
                <MDBInput label="Your name" icon="user" group type="text" validate error="wrong"
                  success="right" />
                <MDBInput label="Your email" icon="envelope" group type="email" validate error="wrong"
                  success="right" />
                <MDBInput label="Confirm your email" icon="exclamation-triangle" group type="text" validate
                  error="wrong" success="right" />
                <MDBInput label="Your password" icon="lock" group type="password" validate />
              </div>
              <div className="text-center">
                <MDBBtn color="primary">Register</MDBBtn>
              </div>
            </form>
          </MDBCol>
        </MDBRow>
      </MDBContainer>
    );
  }
}

export default Registration;
```

Actual outcome

[image]

Expected outcome

[image]

Comment: You might want to check https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help so that your code is rendered in a readable form in the question.

Comment: Thank you, I believe it is readable now.